# Google Map labels language doesn't change after device locale changed

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-android-api-2

I have Google Map embedded in my Android App.

When user changes device locale, using settings, and returns to app, app layout and texts change to new language, but Google Map labels and markers are still in previous language, closing app will not help, only force close will force Google Map to load texts again in new language.

How can I ask/force Google Map to load new labels when device locale changed?

Comment: can a locale changed broadcast receiver help you ?

Comment: How can I send it? @VivekMishra

Comment: By registering a broadcast receiver for locale change event.

Comment: Ok, but then after how can I tell Google Map to reload labels new language?

Comment: When you change the locale, broadcast receiver onReceive() method will receive that change event and here you can reload your google map

Comment: The problem is Google Map has no reload option which refreshes label language!

Comment: Are you using map fragments ?

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, using Map Fragment

Comment: In that case you can remove the old map fragment and add it again but that will need some modifications in the original code like instead of defining map fragment directly in your xml load it dynamically via code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
    Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(ctc, SplashActivity.class);
                int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
                PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctc, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)ctc.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, 
              mPendingIntent);
                System.exit(0);
```